# SOQL order by is not working properly

Tags: apex, soql

In my code i have used a SOQL as below :

```
select id,Name from Object__c where Field__c !='' order by Name
```

But result is getting sorted wrong as :

P-10358
P-10359
**P-1036** 
P-10360

ideally P-1036 shouldn't be there .....Help me understand. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how the [SOQL ordering](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) is defined to work: sorting is based on the individual characters looked at from left to right; there is no special interpretation of numeric characters.

If the name field as an auto-number then you can define its format to be e.g.:

```
P-{000000}
```

that inserts leading zeros so you will get e.g. "P-001036" and "P-010360" that sort in the order you expect.

Otherwise you will have to write your own sort in Apex code (using e.g. [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm)), but that sort will only apply via that code not generally in the user interface.